# MVC resources doesn't import all files

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, dispatcher

In my Dispatcher-servlet i have the mapping for resources with the tag `<mvc:resources`>` from spring mvc:

```
<!-- the mvc resources tag does the magic -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

In my resources folder I have some css, js, fonts, icons and other resources.

Everything works fine, but when i add some new css files to the resources/css folder it doesn't import it to my pages :(

example :

Dispatcher Servlet

```
    <!-- the mvc resources tag does the magic -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

the resources folder
webapp/resources/css/

```
                bootstrap.css(working)
                bootstrap.min.css(working)
                Jquery-Datatables/cssfiles.....(not working)
```

Comment: Do you use maven or something alike for the build process? The probelm could be that the resources dir is relativ to the working dir of the webapp, i.e. `target/<webappName>/resources` and you might have to build the project again, because it doesn't look into your `src` dir. *Or is it a general rule that subdirectories (like Jquery-Datatables/) do not work?*

Comment: Try maven clean -> maven update -> restart server. You can also try refresh browser with Shift+Ctrl+R

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution to the problem

in fact the mcv:ressources doesn't import ressources, it just create a mapping for it
so if we request /resources/css/bootstrap.css from any page anywhere in the web app , it will be redirected to the ressources folder.

the problem i had was with a framework called sitemesh which works like the asp.net Master Page
it's defines a design pattern and import files to all pages specified ...

it was my misunderstanding, thank you